# Regex with prefix and optional suffix

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

This is maybe the 100+1 question regarding regex optional suffixes on SO, but I didn't find any, that could help me :(

I need to extract a part of string from the common pattern:

```
prefix/s/o/m/e/t/h/i/n/g/suffix
```

using a regular expression. The **prefix** is constant and the **suffix** may not appear at all, so `prefix/(.+)/suffix` doesn't meet my requirements. Pattern `prefix/(.+)(?:/suffix)?` returns `s/o/m/e/t/h/i/n/g/suffix`. The part `(?:/suffix)?` must be somehow more greedy.

I want to get `s/o/m/e/t/h/i/n/g` from these input strings:

```
prefix/s/o/m/e/t/h/i/n/g/suffix
prefix/s/o/m/e/t/h/i/n/g/
prefix/s/o/m/e/t/h/i/n/g
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If this is the whole string, you can use `^prefix(.*?)(?:\/(?:suffix)?)?$` as a general pattern, not sure about the concrete implementation (and correct escaping) in java .

Comment: Yes, that it is, thanks a lot! Put it as an answer, please

Comment: Is the input allowed to contain characters before or after the match, i.e. something like `...prefix/s/o/m/e/t/h/i/n/g/suffix...`?

Comment: @Thomas no, strings are strict prefixed. The suffix is also strict if any. The right pattern was just posted. Take a look on the comment earlier

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
prefix\/(.+?)\/?(?:suffix|$)
```

The regex need to know when the match is done, so match *either* `suffix` or end of line (`$`), and make the capture **non greedy**.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pH3vW4/3).

Comment: this doesn't match next example - prefix/s/o/m/e/t/h/i/n/g/suffixandmore

Answer (score 1):

Try `prefix(.*?)(?:/?(?:suffix|$))` if there are characters allowed before `prefix` of after `suffix`.

This requires the match to be as short as possible (reluctant quantifier) and be preceeded by one of 3 things: a single slash right before the end of the input, `/suffix` or the end of the input. That would match `/s/o/m/e/t/h/i/n/g` in the test cases you provided but would match more for input like `prefix/s/o/m/e/t/h/i/n/g/suff` (which is ok IMO since you don't know whether `/suff` is meant to be part of the match or a typo in the suffix).

Comment: That would only make the `x` in suffix optional.

Comment: @ClasG you're right, I'll fix that. Also forgot the `/`.

Comment: Due to greedy matching, the first group will always consume the whole string.

Comment: I suggest you test your RE's at regex101 or similar before posting them ;) That's not working either - [see here](https://regex101.com/r/mQ5mA9/2).

Comment: @ClasG I tested it but my testing tool fooled me.