# Regex make last part of string optional and capture everything if it is optional

Tags: regex, pcre

I have the following expression:

```
(\/.*)@gram_bot
```

I want to match:

```
/echo@gram_bot
/echo
```

But if @gram_bot is in the string, I want to capture everything before it, this already works. However if there is no @gram_bot in the string, I then want to capture the whole string as long as it starts with `/`. How can I accomplish this?

I got it working like this:

`(?:(\/.*)@gram_bot|(\/.*))`

However is there a better way. Right now I'm doing it with two seperate groups, I would prefer 1 group and less steps as possible.

Comment: Follow [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39723275/regex-with-prefix-and-optional-suffix), use https://regex101.com/r/ZziRG7/1 or https://regex101.com/r/ZziRG7/2/. No need of any complex structures, simple non-greedy matching with an alternation or an optional group.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That solution has the more steps compared to the other answers.

Comment: The linked thread doesn't provide a solution with "less steps" as asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can eventually use a "tempered quantifier":

```
/(?:(?!@gram_bot).)*
```

(You don't have to escape the slash if you choose an other pattern delimiter like `~`)

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ln0z6X/1)

In less steps, but with a longer pattern, you can also use an unrolled loop like this:

```
/[^@\n]*(?:@(?!gram_bot)[^@\n]*)*
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/SFI1sF/1)

It's called *"unrolled"* because it's a more efficient version of `/(?:[^@\n]|@(?!gram_bot))*`

Finally, if you want only one group in an alternation, you can use a branch reset group:

```
(?|(/.*)@gram_bot|(/.*))
```

In a branch reset group, each capture group has the same index (the group 1).

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/6e4pOk/1)

But this last way is from far less efficient since it needs two branches and doesn't start with a literal character.

Answer (score 0):

`(\/[^@]*)(?:@gram_bot)?`

This should do what you want, using a non capturing group (?:) and a conditional 0 or 1 with `?` for the group itself.

Now if `@gram_bot`is not fix you'll need to be a but more specific, assuming your bot is always after the first @ you can use:

`(\/[^@]*)(?:.*)?`

You can play with that on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/LpxJaf/1) to see how this works with the explanations on the right side of the window

Comment: Your first expression doesn't seem to match:

https://regex101.com/r/zfUQG6/1

Comment: Indeed it capture all, sholud be `(\/[^@]*)` too.